# realm is compatible with electron - react? - error when integrating

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, realm

Hello I am trying to integrate realm to my electron react application to save data, I apologize since I am new here and I do not know if my question is well formulated but I ask for your help.

I am integrating realm in my electron - react application as the realm documentation says https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/node/integrations/electron-cra/#std-label-node-electron-cra -client-quick-start

when I run the application I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (external "react":1)
    at l (index.html:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.7f1bb50c.chunk.js:1)
    at l (index.html:1)
    at r (index.html:1)
    at Array.t [as push] (index.html:1)
    at main.7f1bb50c.chunk.js:1
```

It's supposed to show me the Reaction logo spinning and it doesn't
[image]

my public/electron.js

```
const path = require('path');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
let mainWindow;
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true },
  });
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  console.log(__dirname);
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'));
}
// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

my craco.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      target: 'electron-renderer',
      externals: [
        nodeExternals({
          allowlist: [/webpack(\/.*)?/, 'electron-devtools-installer'],
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

my package.json

```
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "craco build",
    "start": "electron .",
  },
```

the `"build": "craco build"` command created some files that I will not share since they are very large, I would greatly appreciate any help friends

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps on the Realm tutorial exactly and had no issues with the starting template. Double check your package.json `homepage` and `main` fields? For what its worth, I remember seeing a similar error but that occurred while I was using `electron-forge init` with a typescript + react template. Had no idea how to fix that one.

I encountered another issue when I started to use React hooks with the Realm tutorial and since I feel that it can be commonly encountered error, I'm gonna add my solution to that here as well. The error I got was:

```
Uncaught Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /mnt/bla/test2/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/arrayWithHoles.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

To resolve this, I looked into how craco works and changed the craco file's externals fields to look like this:

```
externals: [
    nodeExternals({
        allowlist: [/babel(\/.*)?/],
    }),
],
```

nodeExternals lists all files in node modules minus anything whitelisted by allowlist. Webpack takes this list and excludes them from bundling (i.e. forcing the code to require those files). Since the error was saying that it can't require the babel file, I figured that importing it might work so i let babel bundle the babel modules and the problem was resolved. I have no idea how this related to the usage of react hooks though.